# Test Cases Management Tool / Application / Software

Tags: testing, testcase

Please suggest some good tool / software / application for managing test cases for an internet software product. Requirements:

- should not be too expensive
- should preferably be on an online platform (but desktop app too is okay!)
- should support custom fields to classify / categorize test cases according to various dimensions like product module, persona etc.

It can be something that you use(d) in your organization or something you know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using informUp which is a [test case management](http://www.informup.com/TestUp-Test-Management-Tool.aspx). we are using it as hosed solution but you can install the server on your site. it is simple but yet powerfull and allow customzied the fields. we are using it for bugs as well but you can use it only for tests cases. we are very satisfied with it